# laravel pass data from View to controller : Missing required parameters for [Route: ]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to pass some data from my view to my controller in order to display data using the selected month, I am not sure if the month numbers or the Eloquent query I am doing is correct,
here is what I have got so far.

My routes:

```
Route::get('dcmlog/monthly','LogController@monthly');

Route::resource('dcmlog', 'LogController');
```

Controller:

```
public function monthly($id)
{
     $dcmlogs = log::with('users')
     ->whereMonth('created_at', '=', $id))
     ->paginate(15);
    return view('dcmlog.index', compact('dcmlogs'));
}
```

My index view:

```
<h>Display a logs by month <h>
<a href="{{action('LogController@monthly'),$post['id'] }}">
{{ $id=Form::selectMonth('month')}}</a>
```

I am getting the following error when running the page

> Missing required parameters for [Route: ] [URI: dcmlog/monthly/{id}].

Comment: Try to add `id` in route, like: `Route::get('dcmlog/monthly/{id}','LogController@monthly');` See my answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing **id** parameter in route:
`Route::get('dcmlog/monthly','LogController@monthly');` should be
`Route::get('dcmlog/monthly/{id}','LogController@monthly');`

[Routing with parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#required-parameters)

and Action syntax has error:
`<a href="{{action('LogController@monthly'),$post['id'] }}">` should be
`<a href="{{action('LogController@monthly', $post['id']) }}">`

[URL generation for controllers action](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/urls#urls-for-controller-actions)

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications!
 I am getting the following error now which says
"Undefined variable:post"

Comment: exactly... have you passed the array `$post` from your controller to this view?

Comment: No I haven't, care to elaborate on how to do that? and why would I pass an array from the controller before it is called, isn't the View supposed to call the Controller?

Comment: from where (which controller or route) you come to (called) this view???
Whats in the $post array?

Comment: I am only trying to get whatever option the user picks from the months list and send it to the controller.
when hard coding the value 1 to the controller i am getting the expected results.

Answer (score 2):

Add ID parameter to your route like this

```
Route::get('dcmlog/monthly/{id}','LogController@monthly');
```

After this you can access the value of id in your controller.

You can see docs here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#required-parameters

Answer (score 2):

Add a router:    `Route::get('dcmlog/monthly/{id}','LogController@monthly')->name('blah');`

Pass `id` var as parameter in view `<a href="{{action('LogController@monthly'),$post['id'] }}">`
or `{{route('blash',['id'=>$post['id']])}}`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing to add an `id` in your route. Just add it and you've fixed!

See this [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-parameters) for more info!

Add it Like:

```
Route::get('dcmlog/monthly/{id}','LogController@monthly');
```